# Keep only certain lines in a text file using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, request, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a script that lets me fetch the "solidfiles.com" links from certain website. I have got all the href links. But, I'm failing to keep only solidfiles.com links using python.

[This is the website I'm trying to fetch links from](https://animetosho.org/view/jacobswaggedup-kill-la-kill-bd-1280x720-mp4-batch.n677876)

This is my current script :-

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import fileinput

Link = 'https://animetosho.org/view/jacobswaggedup-kill-la-kill-bd-1280x720-mp4-batch.n677876'
q = requests.get(Link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(q.text)
#print soup
subtitles = soup.findAll('div',{'class':'links'})
#print subtitles


with  open("Anilinks.txt", "w") as f:
    for link in subtitles:
        x = link.find_all('a', limit=26)
        for a in x:
            url = a['href']
            f.write(url+'\n')
```

With this, I have written all the links in the text file named "Anilinks.txt". I can't seem to keep only solidfiles links. Any hint would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will probably work (if you already have a .txt file):

```
# Store the links we need in a list
links_to_keep = []
with open("Anilinks.txt", "r") as f:

     for line in f.readlines():
         if 'solidfiles.com' in line:
             links_to_keep.append(line)

# Write all the links in our list to the file
with open("Anilinks.txt", "w") as f:

    for link in links_to_keep:
        f.write(link)
```

---

Or you can filter the links before writing to file, then the last part of your code will look like this:

```
with  open("Anilinks.txt", "w") as f:
    for link in subtitles:
        x = link.find_all('a', limit=26)
        for a in x:
            if 'solidfiles.com' in a['href']:
                url = a['href']
                f.write(url+'\n')
```

Comment: worked  like a charm and thanx for the explanation via comments. One more thing. As you can see that on the main website (animetosho), this has 25 episodes, but, this python script is showing only 24 links. Any idea.?

Comment: @user2408212 Wait a second, I'll install BeautifulSoup and test it.

Comment: @user2408212 The problem is in the line `x = link.find_all('a', limit=26)`. Limit 26 is too little so some links we need don't pass it (as I understand). Anyway, when I changed it to 100, all the links were there.

Comment: I have tried 100, still giving me 24 links. 25th is not showing up. And I have even tried removing the limit. But, well, leave it I guess. I'll see to it. Thanx for solving what I asked for :)

Comment: @user2408212 Strange, I get all 25 links. You're welcome:)