# python to find line within a text file

Tags: python, file-read

I have a text file with entries like these:

```
address-object ipv4 "DRV FIL01"
name "DRV FIL01"
ID 00000000-0000-002a-0100-c0eae46ae3f4
zone LAN_General
host 10.4.12.7

address-object ipv4 "DRV FIL02"
name "DRV FIL02"
ID 00000000-0000-002b-0100-c0eae46ae3f4
zone LAN_Management
host 10.4.11.11
```

I would need a python script to go through the file, keep the following lines that start with `name` and `host` and ignore the rest:

```
name "DRV FIL01"
host 10.4.12.7

name "DRV FIL02"
host 10.4.11.11
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Help with what?  You apparently haven't even tried to solve this yourself.

Comment: Please post the code that you have (if you don't have any, try doing it yourself before asking).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep only certain lines in a text file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32765091/keep-only-certain-lines-in-a-text-file-using-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```py
file = open("file.txt")
for line in file:
    if(len(line)>3):
        if(line[0:4]=="name" or line[0:4]=="host"):
            print(line)
    if(len(line)==0):
        print()
```

What it does:

1. Open file
2. iterate over lines in file
3. (In loop of 2) if the length of the line is at least 4
4. (In `if` of 3) if it starts with `name` or `host`
5. (In `if` of 4) print the line
6. (In loop of 2) otherwise, if its length is 0 (meaning empty line)
7. (In `if` of 6) print an empty line

This seems to be what you are asking for.  Just remember next time to post the code that you have tried, and (if any) the error messages.  If you don't have any code, remember that Stack Overflow is NOT a free code writing service, so try it yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

Based on spacing and `with open` method:

```
data = []

with open("file.txt", "r") as msg:
    for line in msg:
        if line.strip() != "":
            if line.split(' "')[0] == 'name' and line.split('" ')[1].split()[0] == 'host':
                data.append(line.strip())

print (data)
```

With this version you match only lines containing `name "smth" host`.

And the regex version:

```
import re

data = []

with open("file.txt", "r") as msg:
    for line in msg:
        if re.match(r"name.+host.+",line):
            data.append(line.strip())

print (data)
```

Output:

```
['name "DRV FIL01" host 10.4.12.7', 'name "DRV FIL02" host 10.4.11.11']
```

With the regex version you match all lines containing 'name' and 'host'.

Comment: *Similar* to what? There is no code in the question...

Comment: Similar to the other answer.

Comment: You shouldn't base your answer on other answers. Answers can be deleted or changed and then your answer might lose context. Make your answers stand on their own

Comment: Using one introduction word in one answer is not "to base one answer on another". Plus, we all base our answers on others. Otherwise it would be full of duplicates for one question thread. However, as rigorousness never hurts, I edit.

Comment: Just to clarify, I wasn't criticizing or saying something was *wrong* with your answer. You can base your answer and reference other answers, but it should be done with a link or a clear indication. The way you wrote was very vague. What if another answer comes along? It is not clear to which one you're talking about. Take it as a tip, not criticism

Comment: You're right, Tomerikoo :). That's why I corrected. On your side, please know that I'm always more playing than rude! Good night!

Comment: No worries :) Didn't take it bad, but as you know it's hard to read reactions online so I just wanted to make clear ***you*** didn't take it bad. Good day ;D